# Apache rewrite to remove "www" not working (globally)

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I've taken the [Apache Server Configs](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache) global `.htaccess` file and placed it on my web server, as `/etc/apache2/apache-server-configs.conf`. Then in my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file I've got this towards the end of my file:

```
# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see the comments above for details.

# Apache Server Configs
Include apache-server-configs.conf

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

The file `apache-server-configs.conf` is being included properly, yet this block of code fails to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

(there is a `RewriteEngine on` statement above this block, several lines up)
If I put that within a single domain's `.htaccess` file, it works as expected. But on a global level, it does nothing. I attempted to debug using `RewriteLog` and the log file was empty when I visited my website.

What am I missing?

**Debian 7.5, apache 2.2.22**

**EDIT 8/2/2014: Adding more info**

---

It's also worth noting that if I include a conf file in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and I put any `RewriteRule` calls in the included file, *none* of them work, period. Other things within the conf file work just fine, but rewrites do not.

**test.com virtual host file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
  ServerName  test.com
  ServerAlias www.test.com
  Options -Indexes

  <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
    AssignUserID bob bob
  </IfModule>

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/bob/www/test.com

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/bob/logs/test.com/error.log
  CustomLog /home/bob/logs/test.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
     #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/test.com/ca-bundle

     ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
     ServerName test.com
     ServerAlias www.test.com
     Options -Indexes

     <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
       AssignUserID bob bob
     </IfModule>

     DocumentRoot /home/bob/www/test.com
     ErrorLog /home/bob/logs/test.com/error.log
     CustomLog /home/bob/logs/test.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `RewriteEnging on` before those settings?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yes, there is a `RewriteEngine on` statement above that block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#vhosts), rewrite conditions are not by default inherited by child Virtualhost blocks. Taken from the docs, it is suggested that they can be set to inherit like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

You would have to set this on each Virtualhost that needs to inherit the Rewrite rules you've set in the main configuration file.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work.

Comment: It should. Could you post an excerpt of the relevant parts of your Virtualhost block? [cough]Anddidyourestart?[/cough]

Comment: Yes, definitely reloaded/restarted. I've posted the virtual host conf file above.

Comment: Oops, I did it wrong! Now it works :)